# Different responses in console when XMLHttpRequest is called

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

So, I was sending an XMLHttpRequest directly from the browser console and from the extension that I am developing. On both of those calls, I get the response, but the one that I call from the extension is shorter (by far). It is not identical response as the one run from the console.

What am I missing? I am not getting any of those CORS errors nor errors of any type.

Here is the code that I use in both of console and from extension:

```
function reqListener () {
  let html = this.responseText
  console.log( html )
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "https://www.freelancer.com/projects/graphic-design/design-converting-pages-sketches-adobe/?w=f");
oReq.send();
```

Note that this is run while I am logged in on the website and while I am on the website (CORS).

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the URL under permissions in your manifest file?

```
"permissions": [
    "https://www.freelancer.com"
 ],
```

Comment: Yes, I did that.